# Codeigniter: Set_uderdata returning NULL

Tags: php, codeigniter

Is this normal that `$this->session->set_userdata()` is returning null? My controller is this.

```
function set_supplier() {

    //UNSET THE OLD DATA 
    if($this->session->userdata('supplier_data')) {
        $this->session->unset_userdata('supplier_data');
    }

    $supplier_id = $this->encrypt->decode($this->input->post('supplier'));

    $sess_array = array();           
    $sess_array = array(
             'id' => $supplier_id                
     );

    $process = $this->session->set_userdata('supplier_data', $sess_array);

    if($process) {
          //SUCCESS
            $this->session->set_flashdata('success', 'You have set the supplier!');
            redirect($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], 'refresh');
         } else {
          //ERROR
            $this->session->set_flashdata('error', 'Oops! An Error has Occured!');
            redirect($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], 'refresh');              
    }

}
```

I simply added `var_dump($process);` to show what's going on and it is showing `NULL`

What I want to happen is to return a message when `$process` is true.

Answer (score 0):

`$this->session->set_userdata('data_here');` **does not return** a boolean on success or failure.

To verify that the userdata is set, use `$this->session->has_userdata('some_name');`.

More information [can be found in the docs](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html#adding-session-data)

Answer (score 0):

This won't work because `set_userdata` doesn't return any result.
Take a look at the [code of function](https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/blob/b4d719dc7fb3b010b53c09e7e82f979abf731ff9/system/libraries/Session/Session.php#L701)

```
public function set_userdata($data, $value = NULL)
{
    if (is_array($data))
    {
        foreach ($data as $key => &$value)
        {
            $_SESSION[$key] = $value;
        }
        return;
    }
    $_SESSION[$data] = $value;
}
```

As you can clearly see, this function doesn't return any value.

Answer (score 0):

```
    function set_supplier() {

    //UNSET THE OLD DATA 
    if($this->session->userdata('supplier_data')) {
        $this->session->unset_userdata('supplier_data');
    }

    $supplier_id = $this->encrypt->decode($this->input->post('supplier'));

    $sess_array = array();           
    $sess_array = array(
             'id' => $supplier_id                
     );

    $this->session->set_userdata('supplier_data', $sess_array);

    if($this->session->userdata('supplier_data')) {
          //SUCCESS
            $this->session->set_flashdata('success', 'You have set the supplier!');
            redirect($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], 'refresh');
    } else {
          //ERROR
            $this->session->set_flashdata('error', 'Oops! An Error has Occured!');
            redirect($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], 'refresh');              
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

probably you forgot to include

```
$this->load->library('session');
```

The required session library in your controller.

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->session->set_userdata()
```

Function nothing return value. it is used for store session value. If you want to get session value then used this function `$this->session->userdata('session_name');` i have changes in your script please check now...

```
function set_supplier() {

//UNSET THE OLD DATA 
if($this->session->userdata('supplier_data')) {
    $this->session->unset_userdata('supplier_data');
}

$supplier_id = $this->encrypt->decode($this->input->post('supplier'));

$sess_array = array();           
$sess_array = array(
         'id' => $supplier_id                
 );

$this->session->set_userdata('supplier_data', $sess_array);

$process = $this->session->userdata('supplier_data');

if($process) {
      //SUCCESS
        $this->session->set_flashdata('success', 'You have set the supplier!');
        redirect($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], 'refresh');
     } else {
      //ERROR
        $this->session->set_flashdata('error', 'Oops! An Error has Occured!');
        redirect($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], 'refresh');              
   } 
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Did u try this?
directly setting the condition if user data is set.

if($this->session->set_userdata('supplier_data', $sess_array))